# Хранение данных на Apple Watch

Tags: swift, apple

В приложении на iPhone я могу менять цвет темы и меняю его в на Apple Watch. Когда в приложении выбираю цвет, то он меняется на часах (изменения делаю с помощью WatchConnectivity), но когда выхожу из приложения и на часах и на телефоне и опять захожу на часах, то цвет сбрасывается до цвета по умолчанию. Можно ли хранить переменную отвечающую за цвет в самих часах без доступа к телефону? Или как обратиться к данным на телефоне если приложение не активно?

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняйте переменную, отвечающую за цвет, в хранилище UserDefaults (механизм абсолютно такой же как и на iOS) на самих часах.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/720692)

Comment: Добавил слов ) Вроде и так было ответом, но сейчас с виду больше похоже на ответ )